# KendoUI pager - pager calling web service for each previous datasource

Tags: jquery, json, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI listview that is being combined with a Kendo pager in order to show paged data returned from the server.  This all works completely fine with no problems, the paging and sorting is all done server side and works no problem.

I also have a tree view on the page that is being used to select the current category - when the selected node in the tree is changed, the listview and pager are updated with a new datasource.  So far, so good.

The problem occurs when I attempt to move to another page after this, the pager/listview sends a request to the server for each of its previous datasources.

So for example, say I set the datasource to category 14, then to category 15, I get a request for 14 and 15 on the server with the relevant page numbers.  Haven't been able to find anything online about this so it might just be me doing something wrong, but I have also been able to isolate the sample into pretty much just the exact problem and I'm getting the same behaviour.

ListView/Pager

```
function bindGrid(categoryId) {
    var sourceURL = 'api/items/' + categoryId;

    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: "odata",
            transport: {
             read: {
                 url: sourceURL,
                 dataType: "json"
             }
         },
         scrollable: {
             virtual: true
         },
         serverSorting: true,
         serverPaging: true,
         serverFiltering: true,
         pageSize: 8,
         schema: {
             data: function (data) { return data.Items; },
             total: function (data) { return data.Count; },
         },
     });
     $("#pager").kendoPager({
         dataSource: dataSource
     });
     $("#listView").kendoListView({
         dataSource: dataSource,
         template: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
     });
 }
```

TreeView:

```
$("#treeView").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: categories,
    dataTextField: "Name",
    dataValueField: "CategoryId",
    select: function (e) {
        var currentCatId = this.dataItem(e.node).CategoryId;
        bindGrid(currentCatId);
    }
});
```

Comment: I do not understand the question. You said it is going to the server each time you page. Isn't this the expected behavior? After all you create new dataSource each time that points to that new specific URL

Comment: The expected behaviour is that it goes back to the server each time I page with a request for the current data source.  The actual behavior I'm getting is that it's making a request to the server for the current data source AND all previous data sources.

Comment: How many times do you call `bindGrid`? If you call it multiple times and you do not destroy whatever you had before in `pager` and in `listView` you are actually binding multiple Pagers and ListViews to these elements and then what you see might make sense. What is the purpose of `bindGrid`?

Comment: ``bindGrid`` (probably not a good name for it!) gets called whenever the selection in the treeview changes. How do I go about about removing the pager/listview that's there already?

Comment: @OnaBai - Thanks for the pointer, I didn't realise that's what was happening when I called that method, I thought it was just updating the existing one.  I've now changed it to use the ``setDataSource()`` method instead of binding it each time and it's working great.  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Glad to help you, I will copy then my comment to the answer so others might find it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you do something like:

```
 $("#pager").kendoPager({
     dataSource: dataSource
 });
 $("#listView").kendoListView({
     dataSource: dataSource,
     template: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
 });
```

you are creating a new KendoUI widget which means that if you invoke `bindGrid` multiple times, you will end up with multiple widgets and then DataSources bound to the same HTML element.

Try either destroying previous content or just -more efficient- triggering a read of the new data.